# Question About Percentage Sum

Tags: statistics, percentages, simulation

I ran a simulation that went as follows:

The percentage chance of an event happening started at 0%.

In each iteration, 0.0103% was added to this percentage chance.

So, for example, on the 3rd iteration the chances of the event happening would be 0.0309%.

In my question, "percentage sum" is the sum of all the previous percentages at each iteration.  At iteration 3, the "percentage sum" would be 0.0103 + (2 * 0.0103) + (3 * 0.0103) = 0.0618%

---

In the simulation, the event happened when the percentage sum was at around 86%.  This confused me, because I figured the percentage sum should be definitely at less than 50% when the event occurred.  My reasoning:

Let's say the chance of an event happening started at 0% and grew by 10% each day.

Day 1:  0% chance the event could happen.
Day 2:  10% chance the event could happen.
Day 3:  20% chance the event could happen.
Day 4:  30% chance the event could happen.

Already at this point, it's likely the event should have already happened, yet the percentage sum is only 10+20+30 = 60%.  So why in my simulation did the event happen at 86%?

NOTE:  I ran the simulation 100 times and took the average, so this isn't some one odd instance.

Comment: `Already at this point, it's likely the event should have already happened` Why? The probability that it did *not* happen during the first $4$ days is $1 \cdot 0.9 \cdot 0.8 \cdot 0.7 = 0.504\,$.

Comment: @dxiv it's 0.492142638 if you don't round to the nearest 10%. doh I was more thinking the original part at least it would be if independent.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee $\;0.9 \cdot 0.8 \cdot 0.7 = \frac{63}{125} = 0.504\,$ without any rounding. Note that the part of the question I commented on has the event as `grew by 10% each day`.

Comment: @dxiv Ah, that's a better way of thinking of it.  Still, the percentage sum got to 86% in my simulation when the event happened.  Wouldn't the probability that the event did not happen before that be less than 50%?

Comment: @InertialIgnorance No, and again, why? That sum is just an artifact you defined, which has no probabilistic meaning on its own. Taking the $0.0103\%$ case for example, the probability that the event does *not* happen during the first $116$ days is $\,\prod_{k=1}^{115} (1 - k \cdot 0.000103) \simeq 0.0502\,$ i.e. still greater than $50\%\,$. Yet, at that point the "*percentage sum*" is $\,\simeq 0.68\,$ i.e. way past $\,50\%\,$ already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your percentage sum is in a sense, the "expected probability" that the event will happen in the first $n$ days. Well so when the event actually happen this number should be close to $100$%. Which $86$% is pretty close. I would say if you perform the experiment like $100000$ times it will be closer to $100$%.

One fundamental misleading intuition for human, which I myself experience too, is that one tends to think an event should happen when the net probability is greater than $50$%. While in reality $50$% only implies the event happening half of the times while $100$% is the real probability that an event should happen.

P.S: For reference, the program below which I wrote gives the average "percentage sum" to be $10081 \over 10000$ which is very close to $100$ percent for $100000$ trials. (I used 0.01% for the daily increase rather than 0.0103%)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

int avg = 0;
int avgc = 0;
int times = 100000;

for(int i = 0; i < times; i ++) {
    int chance = 1;
    int sumchance = 0;
    int itr = 0;
    srand(i);
    bool flag = false;
    while(!flag) {
        int a = rand() % 10000;
        if(a < chance) {
            flag = true;
        }
        itr ++;
        chance += 1;
        sumchance += chance;
    }
    avg += itr;
    avgc += sumchance;
}

avg /= times;
avgc /= times;
cout<<"Iterations: " << avg << ", Chance: " << avgc;
```

}